# European elections and the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, election, european-parliament

As far as I know, the UK legislation required in the UK to hold European elections has been revoked. If Brexit gets delayed and the UK is forced to hold European elections, could the elections be held without the UK legislation that has been revoked? If they can't, would it have to be re-introduced as new (UK) legislation (and go through the full process) or could it be fast tracked?

Answer (score 4):

The legislation enacting European elections has not been revoked yet. It was due to end on March 29th, but that looks unlikely now and if the exit date is delayed then the legislation will remain in force until the new date.

Comment: Is this page wrong then: http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2018/16/schedule/9/enacted ?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix: It's not wrong, it just hasn't come into force yet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_(Withdrawal)_Act_2018#Coming_into_force:_section_25

Comment: … or as explained in § 20 of _the very same Act_.

Comment: @JdeBP section 20 is just definitions.  It defines "exit day."  But the repeals in Schedule 9 *do not take effect on exit day.*  They are enacted by section 23(8), and section 23(8) takes effect, according to section 25, "on such day as a Minister of the Crown may by regulations appoint."  So it is not possible to determine when the schedule 9 repeals will take effect simply by looking at the text of the act.